# How can i speed up this report?

Tags: mysql

Can anyone tell me why this is so slow and how to rectify it please?  It is taking 15 seconds to run even with the "Limit 1" on it.  still takes 10 seconds even without the sub-query.

```
SELECT 
SP_GETCODECODE(t9mod) AS 'Mod',
p.rrnhs AS NHS,
CONCAT(p.idfnam, ' ', p.idnam) AS 'Name',
(SELECT 
        e.c1k
    FROM
        electrolytes e
    WHERE
        p.oid = e.fk_oid
    ORDER BY e.c1date DESC
    LIMIT 1) AS 'Potassium'
FROM
timeline t1
    LEFT JOIN
person p ON t1.fk_oid = p.oid
WHERE
t1.oid = (SELECT 
        t2.oid
    FROM
        timeline t2
    WHERE
        t2.fk_oid = t1.fk_oid
    ORDER BY t2.oid DESC
    LIMIT 1)
    AND t9mod IN (19301 , 19302,
    19304,
    19309,
    19371,
    5106,
    5120,
    140055,
    140067)
    AND p.isactive = - 1
LIMIT 1
```

The idea here is to pull all records from TIMELINE with one of the T9MOD codes as the top entry in the WHERE.  Along with the patient names from the PERSON table and then the sub-query extracts that patients latest potassium from ELECTROLYTES.

I have maxed out my coding abilities in researching and compiling this but cannot understand (as a rookie) how to make it quicker.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Pls post the create table statements including the indexes and the record counts for all involved tables. Pls also post the explain for the above query.

Comment: First you should declare indexes, then try to avoid at all cost subqueries.

I'm not sure it's going to work as expected but I would do something like this : 

`SELECT SP_GETCODECODE(t9mod) AS 'Mod', p.rrnhs AS NHS,  CONCAT(p.idfnam, ' ', p.idnam) AS 'Name', e.c1k AS 'Potassium'
FROM timeline t1
INNER JOIN timeline t2 ON t2.fk_oid = t1.fk_oid 
LEFT JOIN person p ON t1.fk_oid = p.oid 
LEFT JOIN electrolytes e ON p.oid = e.fk_oid 
WHERE  t9mod IN (19301 , 19302, 19304, 19309, 19371, 5106, 5120, 140055, 140067) AND p.isactive = -1
GROUP BY t1.oid
ORDER BY t2.oid DESC, e.c1date DESC
LIMIT 1`